# Check if post has specific tag_ID in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am using Event Manager and they have a custom post type of events, with a taxonomy of event-categories (separate from regular post categories). In that taxonomy I have created terms(?) or event categories, "Education" and "Research". I want a specific `<div>` to show up if a post is in the event-categories taxonomy with the term/category of "Education". The slug is "education" and the tag_ID is 8. Currently I'm trying to use this code snippet, but I'm not getting it. I know there's more to it, but I haven't been successful with other tutorials. Most are for category archives. I need it conditionally for single posts.

```
<?php
   if(in_category('education')) {
      echo '<div>test</div>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`in_category()` is conditional tag for taxonomy 'category'. With custom taxonomies you should use [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional, first parameter is term to check for and second is taxonomy.

```
if ( has_term( 'education', 'event-categories' ) ){
    echo '<div>Test</div>';
}
```

Comment: @chris_s you're very welcome.